# How can I tell if the VirtualBox guest additions were installed on an Ubuntu VM?

Tags: virtualbox

How can I tell if the guest additions are installed on a VirtualBox VM with no X Windows installed?
I'm having a problem mounting a shared directory and I'd like to rule out the possibility that the guest additions weren't installed.

Answer (score 92):

Use `lsmod` from the command line, as it will tell you not only if it's installed, but properly loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep vboxguest
vboxguest             219348  6 vboxsf
```

Comment: @hedgehog answer has been edited to specify that vboxguest is the required module.  You can get the version from `/usr/sbin/VBoxService --version` (as per @Mike_D; requires elevated privileges) or `dpkg -l | grep virtualbox-guest` (as per @voretaq7)

Comment: What does it mean if the command just shows ```vboxguest 349038    5"  ?

Comment: @user3731622: _Any_ result line which starts with the word `vboxguest` means that the guest additions are installed and properly loaded. So you're fine.

Answer (score 36):

1. Open the Session Information window. There are two ways to do it:

   - Select the Machine menu at the top of the VirtualBox window and then Session Information, or
   - Use the key combination <kbd>Host</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> which works for any guest OS i.e. type <kbd>Right CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> (if you use the default <kbd>Host</kbd> key configured by VirtualBox).
2. Select the Runtime Information tab.
3. Look at the Guest Additions version number.
4. (Optional) Compare the the version number with the main VirtualBox version number shown in `Help` | `About VirtualBox...` from VirtualBox Manager).

If the guest additions are not installed and working, then it will report: `Guest Additons: Not Detected`.

Comment: Quick and direct, likely the intended way. Just what I needed.

Comment: it turned out, that this answer is the only really correct resp. useful one! - even `VBoxService --version` showed me once the latest **installed** version, although the loaded/used version was a different one... :-/ **||** not to mention the other answers which only check if any resp. what version is installed, which need not be an indicator what or if any version at all is actually used/loaded.

Comment: If the Session Information window appears and instantly disappears, look on the host screen.

Comment: hmm this didn't work for me - it reports 6.1.40 even though my installed version is 7.0.6!

Answer (score 15):

You can check if the modules are present.

Try:

```
sudo modprobe vboxadd
```

or

```
sudo modprobe vboxvfs
```

This will load the guest additions if they're installed (but usually they would be loaded automatically at boot time anyway).

You'll get an error if the module isn't present. That indicates that the VirtualBox guest additions are not installed properly.

Or you can search for the script that loads the modules:

```
grep vboxadd /etc/init*/*
```

and see if you get any output.

Comment: To get the version: `/usr/sbin/VBoxService --version`

Comment: This answer seems outdated at least for VBox 5.0, I cannot see `vboxadd` and/or `vboxvfs`

Comment: yes, `lsmod | grep vboxguest` shows content, but this does not.

Answer (score 9):

If the extensions were installed using the Ubuntu package repositories (via `apt` or Synaptic) you can check to see if the packages are currently installed:

`dpkg -l | grep virtualbox-guest` will list the guest packages that are currently installed.
`virtualbox-guest-dkms` is the kernel module, and `virualbox-guest-utils` are the command-line utilities.  There may be other packages available (`apt-cache search virtualbox-guest` will list them).

Feiticeir0's answer will also detect the kernel module (if it was installed manually).
If the guest extensions are not installed you can install them the same way you would any other Ubuntu package.

Comment: Be careful installing with `virtualbox-guest-dkms` - that version may not be compatible with your Virtualbox version. You can find the proper VBoxGuestAdditions.iso file at download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox